# What does "figurati" mean?

Tags: meaning

I understand that one meaning of "figurati" is something like "don't mention it", i.e. in response to "grazie".

But I've seen it is used in many more contexts than that, as an expression of surprise, something like "you don't say".  It's difficult for me to understand the meaning of this phrase, and how the different contexts tie together.  How can I understand the meaning of it?

Comment: The second sense is very similar to *go figure!*

Comment: And to complicate things, if pronounced as *figuràti* instead of *figùrati*, it is an adjective (plural of *figuràto*) - meaning "having shape, form or figure", "supplied with pictures", or "made through pictures" (or also "metaphorical, contrived, imagined" - *un esempio figurato*)

Answer (score 20):

The expression *figurati* can be used in different contexts, with different meanings. It seems to me useful to add a well-organised summary of the word-usage.

It's interesting to look at the etymology, but unhelpful: it's difficult to relate it to the modern usage and most Italians just know by heart how to use the word, without ever thinking about it. The mood is imperative, second person, usually limited to one-to-one conversation. Otherwise, with more people it would become "figuratevi".

---

#### 1. Usage as a short single-word reply.

In these cases *figurati* on its own is a complete answer; the extra words shown give the meaning but normally remain unspoken.

**Thank you**

> Mi hai fatto davvero un favore, ti ringrazio(/grazie)
>
> *Figurati!* Non c'è di che. [*don't mention it*]

**Sorry**

> **Scusami** tanto, sono sempre in ritardo.
>
> *Figurati.* Sono arrivato da poco anch'io. [*don't worry*]

**They told me that...** (looking for agreement/support)

> Sai che cosa mi ha detto oggi? Che era in ritardo perché il gatto stava male.
>
> Ah! *Figurati*... E' la solita scusa. [*no way!*]

---

#### 2. Usage in longer sentences

In these cases *figurati* cannot stand alone, as a further explanation is needed.

**Did you know that...** (asking for opinion/chatting)

> Ho sentito dire che il capo ha deciso di cambiare lavoro.
>
> *Figurati se* è vero! Non lo farebbe mai. [very strong *I don't think that..*]

**I discovered that...** (statement, something true)

> Ho scoperto che Franz è bilingue: parla francese e tedesco.
>
> Oh *figurati*... Due lingue così diverse!  [surprised *you don't say*]

---

Facial expression, intonation and so on can play an important role. However, when they change the meaning, it's just for the opposite. So, if you know these five possibilities it's very likely that you can understand also some added irony or Italian hand gestures ;-).

Answer (score 9):

"Figurati" is equivalent to the English expressions 'don't mention it' or 'not at all'.

It can be used also in different context to express  negative reactions or expectations. Usage is important  to familiarise with this expression.

> - Figurati se vado in vacanza con i miei genitori!
>     No way/don't expect that I go on holiday with my parents!
> - Figurati se il mio partito vince  le elezioni!
>     No chance that my political party is going to win  the elections.

Notice that the implicit subject for "figurati" is "tu"; in a formal conversation, you would rather say "si figuri", which employs "Lei".

Answer (score 7):

The verb [*figurare*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/figurare/) is directly from Latin, *figurare*, derived from *figura*, *image*, and this from *fingĕre*, *to shape*, *to model*. It has always been used in Italian since the very beginning (Dante, Boccaccio, etc.).

*Figurarsi* is *figurare a sé*, to mentally depict a real or hypothetic person, thing or situation, without possessing any previous experience, with the aim to figure out how it would be for real.

*Figùrati* is imperative mood, *figure it out by yourself*, and is used to resolutely confirm or deny. It usually means *of course not* or *yes, of course*.

How can you distinguish between the two opposite meanings? By the context, body language, face expressions, etc., there is no other way.

> «Disturbo?»
>
> «Ma figùrati», smiling in a friendly way --> «Of course not!»
>
> «Disturbo?»
>
> «Ma figùrati», smiling with gritted teeth --> «Of course you are, can't you figure it out by yourself? And, of course, if you can't, I can't do it for you and let you know - I just hope you can make it quick and leave soon».

Answer (score 2):

Figurati significa: "immagina", "prova a figurarti (nel senso di immaginare la situazione attraverso illustrazioni mentali)". Infati posso dire "si figuri" o "si immagini" come fossero sinonimi nella stessa situazione. Le "figure" in italiano sono le immagini delle persone e delle cose. Ad esempio a teatro esistono i "figuranti", cioè le comparse che servono alla scenografia, a creare la situazione, lo scenario. "Figurati" nella mente degli italiani non è altro che una rappresentazione scenica di una situazione inverosimile che normalmente capita nella classica commedia teatrale italiana. Per questo si dice "figurati". Agli italiani serve per respingere le scuse o i complimenti ricevuti dagli altri quando sono poco realistici come le caricature di taluni personaggi della commedia classica che si vedono rappresentati a teatro. Gli italiani tendono a scusarsi in maniera eccessiva o a fare complimenti eccessivi rispetto alla realtà, per questo motivo esiste la parola "figurati". Serve a riportare in equilibrio e alla realtà situazioni non correttamente descritte da una sola parte. Figurati è detto da chi reagisce a scuse o complimenti, o da chi sta rappresentando a parole una situazione che presenta parti più o meno ampie di esagerazioni in eccesso o in difetto della realtà, fatta da altri.

Comment: Sarebbe bene rispondere in inglese a una domanda in inglese, anche perché se qualcuno ha problemi a capire “Figurati!”, probabilmente non gli sarà chiarissima neppure una spiegazione dotta come questa...

Comment: @DaG Ma non é vero che qualcuno chi capisce le spiegazioni dotte nella lingua letteraria dovrebbe capire anche le espessioni idiomatice quotidiane. In fatti molti classiciste che sanno capire Cesare (in certo senso di capire) non possono nemmeno sperare di capire uno dialogo colloquiale in latino. Anche io chi parlo latino sono in grado di capire con facilità programmi televisivi italiani sulla storia o politica ma non posso seguire uno dialogo colloquiale di qualsiasi complessità. Le spiegazioni dotte, logiche, che usano parole ben definite, sono molto più facili da seguire per uno studento.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: Non intendevo sminuire l'abilità dell'OP nel comprendere la lingua italiana. È solo una norma più o meno esplicita di questo sito quella di rispondere alle domande nella stessa lingua in cui sono state poste.

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: “Ma non è vero che chi capisce spiegazioni dotte in una lingua letteraria debba capire anche espressioni idiomatiche quotidiane. Anzi, molti latinisti che capiscono Cesare (in un certo senso di capire) non possono nemmeno sperare di capire un dialogo colloquiale in latino. Io, che parlo latino, sono in grado di capire con facilità programmi televisivi italiani sulla storia o sulla politica ma non riesco a seguire un dialogo colloquiale appena appena complesso. Le spiegazioni dotte, logiche, che usano parole ben definite, sono molto più facili da seguire per uno studente”.

Comment: @DaG Nello sito latino si legge quanto segue: "Questions may be asked and answered in English or Latin, preferably with an English summary if in Latin." Per me risposti in italiano sono sempre benvenuti, perché possono sempre essere tradotte in inglese da gli altri utenti - chi forse pensano che questi siano troppo difficili da capire - o utilizzando la traduzione automatica (il cui aiuto anche io sto utilizzando per scrivere questo :P). E altrimenti, leggere risposte nell'italiano aiuta ad imparare la lingua. A proposito, grazie per le correzioni!

Comment: @Unbrutal_Russian: Prego! Non so come funzioni il sito sul latino, ma in questo sito la norma ufficiosa è che “we should answer in English to a question posed in English and in Italian to a question posed in Italian” (cf. https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-questions-answers-to-be-in-italian).

Answer (score 0):

"Figurati" or  "si figuri" are used in response to "scusami" or "mi scusi" respectively, too.

Answer (score 0):

Usually used "figurati" as - forget it.
*-You paid for my coffee so I owe to you 1 Euro

- Forget it! (Figurati!)*

So the best similar meaning "non ti preoccupare" or - please do not care. Very similar is also "di niente" or "For nothing".


Could be somethimes "figurati" as "immagine it" with the informal conversation addressed to person you know.
 *- Figurati che ho visto Barbara ieri sera!*

There are other meanings but I suppose not very common in daily verbal language.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I found this article that explores the differences between figurati and figuriamo:

https://becomingitalianwordbyword.typepad.com/becomingitalian/2014/09/figuring-o.html

Curious, I've never thought too much about it before!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Link-only posts are not considered true answers on SE. May you please summarise the contents of this article?